# Downloading a research paper using command line/terminal

Tags: linux, download, terminal, wget

Is there any way to download a research paper using command line.
I don't have access from home but I can login to my department's server, which is in intranet. So, ideally I should be able to do it, but I am not aware how to get a direct link to the pdf and then *wget* it or may be we can *curl* or *lynx* the paper webpage in remote server and have a pattern match or manual search for the link.

May be someone has already done it. 
Example paper : http://www.nature.com/nprot/journal/v7/n3/full/nprot.2012.016.html

Thanks

Comment: Surprising that there's still no answer!

Answer (score 5):

It seems that some publishers block the Wget user agent.  You can change this using the [--user-agent option](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/wget/wget_9.html).  For example

```
wget --user-agent TryToStopMeFromUsingWgetNow publisher.com/paper.pdf
```

Comment: I tried `wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092416 Firefox/3.0.3" https://springerlink3.metapress.com/content/lr2764511087q412/fulltext.pdf` but it didn't work for [SpringerLink](http://www.springerlink.com/content/lr2764511087q412/?MUD=MP). Thank you, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather the article is for subscribers only and only authenticated users have access to it.

Ideally you should be able to get the URL after access, but that doesn't mean you will be able to `wget` it. Sorry I can't be of better use, but I don't have a Nature subscription.

Comment: Hey Gabe, I dont think so, because if you are in intranet or subscription zone, this same link shows download pdf options. So, the link remains the same, just the option changes after doing the authentication check on the back. _Wget_ will work when you will have the pdf link, which we might get from the page source .
Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried something like (for your example link )

wget http://www.nature.com/nprot/journal/v7/n3/pdf/nprot.2012.016.pdf

And it works for me.

Comment: I think, this hack will differ from journal to journal